# Ubuntu installer for Dell laptops?

Tags: dell, laptop, url

I found a version of ubuntu on this link: http://linux.dell.com/files/ubuntu/precise/12.04-OSP1/

Can anyone tell me if it is the installer for Dell laptops. Or what is this? :O

Have a nice day guys. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dell sold a lot of laptops with pre-installed Ubuntu.

Many of those were with Ubuntu 12.04. I saw some of them.
Dell installed customized packages and drivers, that was a problem with upgrades in some cases.

This must be an OEM image that Dell installed on new laptops..

Comment: You can try it, but I do not recommend using it.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to http://linux.dell.com/ (the 1st part of your URL) you will see it is the official Dell website (or subsite of dell.com).

That's for 12.04 though and the site only has [maverick besides precise](http://linux.dell.com/files/ubuntu/).

*So yes it is the Dell image for OEM installs **but it is old.***